# Adding a new datatype to UML models with Papyrus

Tags: types, profile, papyrus

I'm trying to add new datatypes to my Papyrus installation so that class attributes I will create  could be of these datatypes. 
I defined a profile containing these datatypes (I just made drag-and-drops of widgets from the palette to the editing area). In the same profile I added some stereotypes.

The problem is that after defining the profile, I can access and use stereotypes but none of the datatypes I created is reachable.
After some researches, I learned that

"When defining a Profile containing a Structured DataType, the datatype is transformed to a String property. It should be defined as an EClass instead, so that the structured is maintained."           from https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375029 .

Could someone please help me defining my datatypes as suggested in the above link or in any other way that can make them accessible when building diagrams?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can :

1. Apply the Ecore profile to your model
2. Create a new PrimitiveType in your model
3. Apply EDataType stereotype to your new Primitive type

If this datatype references an already exisiting type, you can add this type into the properties -> EDataType -> instanceClassName.

You can add an URI type which will be generated as org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI, for example.